# Workaround for implementing OpenID Connect in Swagger UI/ Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, identityserver4, openid-connect, swashbuckle

I have two different projects:

1. Auth project: which implements IdentityServer4 to provide authentication as a service
2. API project: which implements Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.5 to generate the Swagger UI

I’m using the `SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect` as a security scheme in the API project and whenever I click on the **Authorize** button I get an empty authorization modal. I believe the problem is because of the OpenIDConnect Discovery is not supported in the Swagger UI. So, I’m just wondering if anyone found a workaround for this issue.

Here is an open issue explain my problem exactly:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1241

Comment: OpenID Connect is now supported in Swagger UI 3.38.0.

Answer (score -2):

Please modify startup.cs like this:

```cs
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
{
    Flow = "implicit",
    AuthorizationUrl = "https://localhost:44394/connect/authorize"
    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "service", "Service" },
    },
});

c.OperationFilter<ApplyOAuth2Security>();
```

And add this private method:

```cs
private class ApplyOAuth2Security : IOperationFilter
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var filterDescriptor = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors;
        var isAuthorized = filterDescriptor.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is AuthorizeFilter);
        var authorizationRequired = context.MethodInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "AuthorizeAttribute");

        if (isAuthorized && authorizationRequired)
        {
            operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                     { "oauth2", new string[] { "openid" } },
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the issue is with SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect. I can get the it working perfectly fine with SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2 and ImplicitFlow